# PHP ngettext() error on Macbook M1 - 13.1 - MAMP Server

Tags: php

I have an fatal error that breaks my website and output

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I did debug the issue and found out that the former dev used [ngettext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php) to get the singular or plural of text.

```
$day = 2;
printf(ngettext("%d day", "%d days", $day), $day;
// Expect output: 2 days
```

I have check all the log, no log in PHP, but there is one in Apache log everytime I try to run `ngettext()` somewhere in my source.

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

### I did:

- Check the `gettext` module enabled.
- I run the code on PHP CLI:

```
$ php -r 'printf(ngettext("%d day", "%d days", 2), 2);'
// Output: 2 days
```

- Deploy the source code into hosting server, it ran well.
- Deploy the source code into another Macbook with Intel chip, v12. Ran well.

What am I missing? Please advise me. TIA

Comment: You do have a syntax error with a missing parathese for `ngettext` : `printf(ngettext("%d day", "%d days", 2), 2);`

Comment: @sglessard Thank you for pointing out. It's just a typo when I was writing this post. In code, it's correct.